# Monitoring individual CPU Cores for multiple VM's

Tags: powershell, monitoring, vsphere, cpu-cores

I have a lot of VMs that have multiple cores. Some apps that run in some VMs are not optimized however for multiple cores and a lot of time one CPU core will be running at a high percentage while the other is barely being used. I'm looking for a way to monitor individual CPU core usage on these servers and output the data that I find to some kind of file (.txt or spreadsheet). I know that it's possible to view directly from vSphere the CPU core usage on servers, however I have too many VMs to sit down and monitor.

Is there any way to do this with Powershell? I would like to be able to create a script that runs automated through task scheduler and gathers the info I want, that way I can decide whether to make changes to certain VMs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand [this article](http://www.lucd.info/2010/01/24/powercli-vsphere-statistics-part-4-grouping/) correctly, [`Get-Stat`](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41/html/Get-Stat.html) should give you per-core statistics.